# Is async method synchronous if await Task is never returned?

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await, thread-safety, deadlock

I have a constructor that is called on UI thread in my WPF app. Inside of it, it calls async method but it must be done in a synchronous way. So I tried to call wait, but it caused deadlock an I understand why. So I introduced argument that indicates if method should be run in a asynchronous or synchronous manner. Something like this:

```
// constructor that is called on UI thread
public MyClass()
{
    Method1(false).Wait();
}

public async Task Method1(bool runAsync)
{
    await Method2(runAsync);
}

public async Task Method2(bool runAsync)
{
    if (runAsync)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(1000));
    }
    else
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

I don't want to use ConfigureAwait because I want everything to run on UI thread. Will Method1(false).Wait(); ever cause a deadlock (is it safe to use)? I tested it a lot and it didn't, but I'm not sure. Finally, my real question is: if 'await Task.Run(...' is never executed, is my method completely synchronous? I found several posts on this subject, but none of them answers directly to my question.

Comment: why can't you have a synchronus version of the same method `an overload probably) which you can use in this case?

Comment: I don't want to duplicate the code. This is very simplified version of my problem.

Comment: Actually you are already duplicating (most probably) with that `if .. else`

Comment: That's the trade-off I can handle :)

Comment: Well then I don't see how it can result in a deadblock at all since there is different execution path

Comment: I think a deadlock could still happen and to be on the safe side I would just write `public Task Method1(bool runAsync) { return Method2(runAsync); }` and forego the await completely which would be responsible for a deadlock when it tries to switch back to original context. Also in Method2 you also just return the Task.Run task and for your synchronous "else" just do `return Task.CompletedTask;`.

Comment: Thank you, Rahul. Ckuri interesting solution, I'll keep in mind if problem occurs. Thanks

Comment: Stop trying to do async stuff at construction. It doesn't belong there and is forcing you to write blocking code (bad). Instead, create an async factory method which news up a purely synchronous constructor with no waiting and then initializes the resulting instance asynchronously, then returns it to the caller. Now you don't have to think about sync/async switching.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a constructor that is called on UI thread in my WPF app. Inside of it, it calls async method but it must be done in a synchronous way.

I'm gonna stop you right there. The best solution is *not* to run synchronous/blocking code on the UI thread. That degrades your user experience. Instead, you should restructure your code so that you're never in this situation in the first place.

When a UI is being shown, the UI framework asks your code for the data to display. Your code should run synchronously *and return immediately* (not blocking). But your code also needs to do some asynchronous work in order to have the data to display. So there's a conflict there.

The solution is to design an intermediate state for your UI, e.g., a "loading..." message or a spinner. Then, when your code starts, it can synchronously/immediately display the "loading" state (and *start* the asynchronous operation), and when the asynchronous data arrives, the code *updates* the UI to the "final" state.

I discuss this pattern in more detail in my article on [async MVVM data](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn605875.aspx).

Comment: The guy whose answer I was hoping for :) Thank you. I am actually using something like that. I am just one of many developers working on a huge app consisted of over 500 modules (lots of legacy code). We had a problem where call to a service from a UI thread got stuck, message queue was flooded and app crashed. So I made that call async combined with some fancy, common "waiting" dialog. But that call also must be done synchronously during app startup (sort of splash screen is shown) and I cannot use that fancy, common dialog.

Comment: And if it is not problem - can you answer me: can my code cause a deadlock (if we ignore for a second the fact its not recommended way to use async)?

Comment: @FrodoBaggins: If you need to support both sync and async callers, I recommend the [boolean argument hack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt238404.aspx). If this is a service call, I'd expect you should be able to use naturally asynchronous APIs rather than `Task.Run`.

Comment: I'm planning to introduce asynchronous APIs, but at this moment it's not the case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrestling with async stuff at construction (your blocking solution isn't so good), why not write an async factory to spew out these objects?

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {

    }

    public async Task Method2(bool runAsync)
    {
        //async immediately
        await Task.Delay(1000); //no Thread.Sleep. Blocking code != good
    }
}
```

then

```
public MyClassFactory
{
    public async Task<MyClass> GetAsync()
    {
        var c = new MyClass();
        await c.Method2();
        return c;
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Thank you. But, I have a lot of legacy code that is rarely changed and i needed a way to make my async method call synced (see my reply to a Stephens answer - I would have to make MyClassFactory.GetAsync call also synchronous) and without lot of changes. Now you can tell me that there is a fast way and a good way to do things, but maintaining a huge app with hundreds of other developers sometimes makes you cut the corners. Can you explain me why my blocking solution isn't so good?